# PHP: What if I call a static method in non-static way

Tags: php, static-methods

I'm not pro in Object Oriented Programming and I got a silly question:

```
class test {
    public static function doSomething($arg) {
        $foo = 'I ate your ' . $arg;
        return $foo;
    }
}
```

So the correct way to call `doSomething()` method is to do `test::doSomething('Pizza');`, Am I right?

Now, what will happen if I call it like this:

```
$test = new test;
$bar = $test->doSomething('Sandwich');
```

I've tested it and it's working without any error or notice or etc. but is that correct to do this?

Comment: Is my question that much not-useful which I deserve to have -1?

Comment: as people say "He that nothing questioneth, nothing learneth" (question is quite basic but I dont see any reason why you got -1) +1

Comment: Why is this question considered to be so basic? I've been doing this for years and I had no clear thought about whether this is bad practice or not, which is what brought me here. This is an excellent question.

Comment: @OCDev the question is quiet old, but thank you. :)

Comment: Timeless questions like this don't get old to those who haven't seen the answer yet. Thank you again for asking it!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Baba already pointed out, it results in an `E_STRICT` depending on your configuration.

But even if that's no problem for you, I think it's worth mentioning some of the pitfalls which may result from calling static methods in a non-static way.

If you have a class hierarchy like

```
class A {
    public static function sayHello() {
        echo "Hello from A!\n";
    }

    public function sayHelloNonStaticWithSelf() {
        return self::sayHello();
    }

    public function sayHelloNonStaticWithStatic() {
        return static::sayHello();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function sayHello() {
        echo "Hello from B!\n";
    }

    public function callHelloInMultipleDifferentWays() {
        A::sayHello();
        B::sayHello();
        $this->sayHelloNonStaticWithSelf();
        $this->sayHelloNonStaticWithStatic();
        $this->sayHello();
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->callHelloInMultipleDifferentWays();
```

This produces the following output:

```
Hello from A!
// A::sayHello() - obvious

Hello from B!
// B::sayHello() - obvious

Hello from A!
// $this->sayHelloNonStaticWithSelf()
// self alweays refers to the class it is used in

Hello from B!
// $this->sayHelloNonStaticWithStatic()
// static always refers to the class it is called from at runtime

Hello from B!
// $this->sayHello() - obvious
```

As you can see, it's easy to achieve unexpected behaviour when mixing static and non-static method calls and techniques.

Therefore, my advice also is:
Use **Class::method** to explicitly call the static method you mean to call.
Or even better don't use **static methods** at all because they **make your code untestable**.

Comment: Your answer deserves to be the accepted answer because of complete explanation and examples. BTW about your last line I think it's not possible to always not use static methods because sometimes the best solution is to use static methods. It saves a lot of code and makes the application simpler and more editable. I can show you too many examples if you want to. Anyway, thanks for your complete answer.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, i too am aware of situations where static functions are quite convenient, but i still prefer a higher grade of testability over the benefits of static. My remark on that topic was only intended  to (at least) provoke a conscious thought about this potentially problematic side-effect of static.

Comment: Wrong. No error or warning is generated for calling static methods with the arrow operator.

Comment: Worth noting that you can call `$test::doSomthing()` as well, which seems correct and has advantages.

Answer (score 4):

It makes no difference if your method don't use `$this` and don't access to static properties.

**Static properties cannot be accessed through the object using the arrow operator ->.**

**$this is not available inside the method declared as static.**

But, you should always use `::` to call a static method, even through php let you call it on an instance.

Answer (score 3):

It is better you call it this way to avoid  `E_STRICT` on some version of PHP

```
$bar = test::doSomething('Sandwich');
```

[FROM PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

> Static properties cannot be accessed through the object using the arrow operator ->. Calling non-static methods statically generates an E_STRICT level warning.

Also

> Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible without needing an instantiation of the class. A property declared as static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a static method can).