# Why does PHP support calling static functions as non-static member methods?

Tags: php, oop, static

Code beforehand fully valid code from 5.0.0 (without E_STRICT or E_DEPRECATED)

```
class A{
    static public function b() {
    }

    public function c(){
        $this->b();
    }
}

$d = new A();
$d->c();
$d->b();
```

It's looks like inconsistent behaviour because you cannot use static properties from instance.

> The PHP way is to steal and borrow from other languages whenever
>   possible ...

But I cannot find any programming language that supports similar behavior.

**Why does PHP support it?** What is the point of calling static methods as non-static?

Some explanation from support: [Expected behavior](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40886)

Comment: I would assume because it was misscorrectly tagged as Duplicate, when it wasn't @PaulCrovella.

Comment: I agree 100% @PaulCrovella. I'm only speculating as to why the OP did what he did.

Comment: Java is an example of such a language.

Comment: @PaulCrovella, it was closed as duplicated. It's hard to restore question from there. Deleted question should not appear in reopen queue.

Comment: @sectus The easiest way is to ping `@Phil`, and explain to him why it's not a reason. Had you explained in a comment/edit that this is a request for reasoning, and [that dupe target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874376/php-what-if-i-call-a-static-method-in-non-static-way) has absolutely no developer reasoning, I'm sure others would agree with you (I personally would have voted to reopen).

Comment: @PaulCrovella, I have tried to restore some time ago some questions and I have failed. Time wasted, nothing has happened. In this case I've used my rights to delete question, and create question. In this case, you can flag this question for moderation attention and point the rule that was violated. And/or you can create post on meta to propose to restrict such tricky way to "reopen" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, C++ and Java support this. It seems the PHP developers, after discussion, decided on implementation to match them.

After a bit of digging, I found [this thread](https://marc.info/?t=107710175500002&r=1&w=2) from February 2004, which is essentially their discussion about the implementation choices. Important tidbits from the discussion:

[From Cristiano Duarte](https://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=107732137915171&w=2):

> > C++ allows $a->bar() when bar() is a static method (yes, it is called
> >     in a static context there too).
> >
> > IMO, there should be no error, warning or notice here.
>
> I Agree. PHP is fine the way it is.

[From Art](https://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=107741579229348&w=2):

> Regardless of the final implementation, I think access to static methods and 
>   static class variables should be consistent.  Currently, you cannot access a 
>   class variable via an object instance.
>
> And for what it's worth, I see no reason why static methods cannot be called 
>   from objects.  Follow Java/C++ in this case.

Ultimately, a final decision [From Wez](https://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=107757434712873&w=2):

> Please drop this thread; we're not changing the behaviour of static.

Comment: It is a little bit tricky to call static method of parent class of instance in Java.

Comment: @sectus I agree, and the full thread goes into a little bit more detail on that. (I recommend giving it a full read, if you're curious).

Comment: Sure, I am curious.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that it is just a syntax consideration here. Nothing here is inconsistent with the logic of static methods, it's still impossible to use `$this` in your static function, and therefore the function will not have access to instance properties or methods. It feels more like a shortcut than an inconsistency to me.

I have no use case of that, but I guess someone may find it useful with objects created with dynamic class names: you can still use the function even if you don't know it's class name.

Comment: Why static properties cannot be used in the same way?

Comment: this can seem inconsistent, yes, but it's actually possible to get a static property from an instance with the syntax `$d::$b`, though you cannot use the arrow here, which is a bit inconsistent syntax i admit